# C# WPF Listbox Group Header Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm using a Listbox to show multiple items.
The items are grouped. Now I want to edit the header style but the only thing happens is that the text isn't shown anymore.

Thats my xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbTreatments" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="473" Margin="10,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="309" FontSize="13">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding subcategoryName}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And thats my code to group the items:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(treatmentsCategory);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("subcategoryName"));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("subcategoryName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
lbTreatments.ItemsSource = view;
```

The items are grouped but the header text is missing. If I delete the Groupstyle from xaml the text will be shown. Can anybode help me please?

Comment: use `Name` for your group header XAML. i.e. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>`

Comment: Ok its working, thanks.
But why name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle.headertemplate.aspx) says:

> Each group is of type CollectionViewGroup.

The actual data type is [CollectionViewGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.aspx) which doesn't have a `subcategoryName` property so the binding will fail. Instead you have to use the `Name` property, which will already be set to the value from `subcategoryName`.

As such, use this...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

...in your header template to get the group name.

Comment: Is there a way to add a linebreak to the output before the name?

Comment: Something like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, StringFormat={}&#x0a;{0}}"/>`?